# Detecting if the JavaScript has been stripped out of an HTML mail attachment?

Tags: javascript, html

I send out an email which has an html attachment. Some recipients read the mail on a specific web portal (NHS webmail, which is MS Exchange), and try to save the attachment from the portal. However, the JavaScript is silently stripped out of the attachment, and the recipient ends up with a blank page. All script tags are stripped out- even links to external scripts.

Question: are there any smarts I can put in the html, so that the user is notified that they have a useless page, instead of ringing me to ask why there's nothing on it? I know it's a long shot, but I don't know much html, and I thought it was worth a try. If it helps, the user is unlikely to be using IE6, IE7, or IE8.

Thanks.

Comment: In email you might be able to use the old <noscript></noscript> to show a message when javascript is off but that might not show if javascript is stripped off but still on. Javascript should be avoided in email anyway to many security risk so email client often take it out.

Comment: @gillesc I think the OP is talking about the case when some webmail clients "clean-up" the attachments of any script tags. Therefore, when you save it to your harddrive - no useful scripts remain inside.

Comment: @Max Ah if that's the case I guess need to do the old Outloook trick and send attachment as archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a tag:

`<div id="noScriptsFound">Sorry, your page is messed up by your lame mail agent. Please download it in some other way</div>`

Then add a script (directly after the `div` to execute asap):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("noScriptsFound").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Now, if something cuts off your 'script' tags while saving an attachment, the browser will not execute the script tag, therefore the text will remain visible.

Comment: Works, with the complication that it also triggers my <noscript> message, so the user gets both. I think the easiest thing to do is to combine the noscript and 'scripts-disappeared' messages. Thanks.